# SCORM package is not communicating with LMS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, scorm, scorm2004

Even after Initialize, SCORM package is not communicating with the LMS-

Throwing error -

**No SCORM implementation found.**

My Folder structure-

```
-index.php
-player.php
-course/SCORM-course (directory)
-wrap.js
-SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js
```

All code -

My index.php code - http://pastebin.com/e8fcvxep

My Player.php code - http://pastebin.com/R0zRaVXJ

My wrap.js code - http://pastebin.com/Lte4eTKu

My SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js code - http://pastebin.com/kdQ0JR04

I searched and tried everything that I can but still unable to resolve. let me know what else we need to edit to make it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using SCORM 2004, you need to have the API wrapper in a frame named **API_1484_11**. You currently have the API frame called **API** which refers to SCORM 1.2.

For example, in **player.php**, you would change the line:

`<frame src="SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js" name="API" noresize>`

to

`<frame src="SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.html" name="API_1484_11" noresize>`

Where `SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.html` is a html file that references `SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js`.

This is since according to the api discovery agorithm, a frame named "API" refers to SCORM 1.2 not SCORM 2004. The API discovery algorithm loops through the current window and its frames, and the windows opener if applicable looking for an element named "API_1484_11".

A good resource on API discovery algorithms is available from Rustici at: http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/api-discovery-algorithms/

Comment: Excellent...working now..+1 and WoW...source for SCORM seems to be little available but with the help of stack community I m learning it..basics are getting clear now :) thx for the response :)

Comment: @kernelPanik : Guys, i'm also building a LMS system for reading SCORM 1.2 package. I followed your given procedure but, don't know why it's not working.

I've post my problem at here : http://goo.gl/ikWmYf

Can u guys, help me a bit to resolve it.

Reagards